# Product owner for SaaS app

Tags: scrum, agile, product-owner, product

I am developing a SaaS app using Scrum and wondering if there are any best practices when it comes to having multiple "Product Owners". This is because I am working with some "users" who will help balance requirement from potential users. Just wondering if this will ever work out.

So far it has been extremely taxing since each "Product Owner" seem to have an epic list of cards.

Comment: One Product Owner per project. Period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide.pdf) Page 5:

> The Product Owner is one person, not a committee. The Product Owner may represent the 
>   desires of a committee in the Product Backlog, but those wanting to change a Product Backlog 
>   item’s priority must address the Product Owner.

Comment: I totally agree, except when the product is big enough to require something more like the Scaled Agile Framework or some such to manage. Then you typically have Product Owners empowered to make decisions inside a sub-set of the overall product.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, you will certainly have multiple stakeholders from in and out of the organization, but only one Product Owner -- whose role calls for her to represent and prioritize based on these various interests.